# :hover works but rest of the link states don`t (:link & :visited for example)

Tags: html, css

For unknown to me reason, for a div with "TWO" inside:

`:hover` state works fine
`:link`, `:visited` don`t work

I can't find why?

```css
.menu:link {
  color: teal;
}

.menu:visited {
  color: red;
}

.menu:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>
    <div class="menu">ONE</div>
  </a>
  <a href="smth.html">
    <div class="menu">TWO</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:visited` and `:link` selectors are used with `<a>` tag.

```css
a:visited > .menu{
  color: red;
}
a:link > .menu {
  color: teal;
}
a:hover > .menu {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>
    <span class="menu">ONE</span>
  </a>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">
    <span class="menu">TWO</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

by the way, I don't think it is a good idea, to use `div` inside `a`

Comment: THX! i need the div field to be the link itself, thats why i wrapped it like that. There might be a better way though... The funny thing is the hover state was still working without <a> tag

Comment: ps. what would be the correct code for an :active class to work now? 
a:active > .menu{} & add the class="active" to html?